# React hover to show image. Hover isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Still trying to learn React. I'm trying to show an image when you hover. This is my Item component.

```
import React from 'react';


import Eyecon from '../../static/eye.svg';


class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.displayName = 'Item';
        this.state = {
            hover: false
        };
    }
    mouseOver() {
        this.setState({hover: true});
    }
    mouseOut() {
        this.setState({hover: false});
    }
    render() {
      const { item, i } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="grid-box" onMouseOver={this.mouseOver} onMouseOut={this.mouseOut}>
            {this.state.hover ? (<img src={Eyecon}/>) : null}       
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Item;
```

How would I make it so only the item I hover over shows the image?

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: does it show when you set hover to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a 'this' binding issue. Put a console.log inside of your mouseOver and mouseOut methods and you'll notice that your state isn't changing.

There are many ways to bind the 'this' context in your class methods. I'll show you three ways to do it in this example (DO NOT do all three methods, just choose one).

```
import React from 'react';
import Eyecon from '../../static/eye.svg';

class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.displayName = 'Item';
        // 1. bind your functions in the constructor.
        this.mouseOver = this.mouseOver.bind(this);
        this.mouseOut = this.mouseOut.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            hover: false
        };
    }

    // 2. bind it with fat arrows.
    mouseOver = () => {
        this.setState({hover: true});
    }
    mouseOut() {
        this.setState({hover: false});
    }
    render() {
      const { item, i } = this.props;
        // 3. bind them in the render method (not recommended for performance reasons)
        return (
            <div className="grid-box" onMouseOver={this.mouseOver.bind(this)} onMouseOut={this.mouseOut.bind(this)}>
            {this.state.hover ? (<img src={Eyecon}/>) : null}       
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Item;
```

Here's an explanation of different ways to bind your 'this' context in react using ES6 classes:
http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html

Comment: I get this error in console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null

Comment: @Dileet is that the error you got originally or after you made changes? / What changes did you make?

Comment: I added the binding in the constructor.

Comment: interesting, maybe I made a mistake, did you have any error before you made any changes? I'll test this out in the mean time

Comment: try binding directly in the render method like I did on option 3. Both option 1 and 3 are working for me on jsfiddle

Comment: @Dileet check out this fiddle, I test it in the constructor and int he render method and they both work. http://jsfiddle.net/buj13nyv/

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I really cannot understand why people would rather add bindings everywhere instead of just changing the function to an ES6 arrow function. It's a 3 character change and solves all this headache.

Comment: I had that in my original answer but removed it because it wasn't working in the fiddle. I just added it back in as another option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you have to bind `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` calls in order to use `this.setState` inside them.

Replace:

```
<div className="grid-box" onMouseOver={this.mouseOver} onMouseOut={this.mouseOut}>
```

with:

```
<div className="grid-box" onMouseOver={this.mouseOver.bind(this)} onMouseOut={this.mouseOut.bind(this)}>
```

Comment: This is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, it is. [React ES6 class does not autobind this](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding)

Comment: Can you point to the exact phrase you're referring to? I cannot find what you want to show.

Comment: Sure. React's traditional `React.createClass` provided an autobind feature. So, indeed, the binding to `this` was not necessary. But the ES6 `class MyComponent extends React.Component` doesnt have that. So (1) or you prebind all your callbacks in the constructor, (2) bind each call like above, or use (3) arrow functions.  Check [this article](https://reactjsnews.com/composing-components): (...) "The automatic autobinding that React.createClass handles for you can be confusing to beginners (...) ES6 classes make you explicitly bind your methods.".

Comment: Why not just use ES6 arrow functions instead of doing a bunch of bindings? This is what I meant by "not necessary" because there are much easier ways.

Comment: Now I got your's "This is not necessary". You could be more specific. About the use of arrow function, you're right. It's the cleaner option. The answer was just to illustrate the differences and point a visual solution (bind vs. no bind). BTW, @jmancherje's answer is much more complete.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions suggested are perfectly valid, however you can solve this easily by just converting your functions to [**ES6 arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target). Arrow functions are always anonymous.

Like so:

```
mouseOver = () => {
  this.setState({hover: true});
}
mouseOut = () => {
  this.setState({hover: false});
}
```

Simple.

Comment: Just a point. In order to this syntax work ([class properties](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties)) with babel, you need [transform-class-properties plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) and add `{  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"] }` to `.babelrc` file **after** `es2015` preset.

Comment: @mrlew Well, yes, unless you're also using `stage-0` or `stage-1` babel preset. http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/